# not able to show image in popup

Tags: php, javascript, popup

I have this issue: I want to open a image in a pop-up, but the image is not loaded in the pop-up.

Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code, I don't have any errors

This is a part of my code:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query=$db->getQuery (true);
$query->SELECT ('*');
$query->from('#__feature_film_image_data');
$db->setQuery( $query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
?>
<?php foreach($results as $result):?>

<div class="work mr9">
 <a href="<?php echo $result->id; ?>" rel="facebox">
  <img src="<?php echo $result->image; ?>" width="172" height="111">
 </a>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="popup-div">
<?php foreach($results as $result):?>
 <div id="<?php echo $result->id; ?>" style="display:none;">
  <img src="<?php echo $result->image?>" alt="some alt txt">
 </div>
 <br clear="all">

<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<br clear="all">
```

I want to open the pop-up window by clicking (click event) on the image.

Comment: could it be because the image is in a div with the style `display:none` ?

Comment: Post the generated markup and javascript here instead of joomla code

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage : 'images/loading.gif',
        closeImage   : 'images/closelabel.png'
      })
    })

Comment: this one javascript code

Comment: Is the path to the image correct?

Comment: ya remove style="display:none" that time display image under small image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because target div is hidden,you have to change its style  before displaying of image popup.

Here i have used Facebook hook given at Facebook  [github](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) repository.

Add below lines in Jquery ready function to attach   a reveal event of Facebook.

```
$(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() {$('#facebox div.content image>div').parent('div').show() });
```

Comment: no attach reveal event of facebox how to attach the this method

Comment: It that not working??? I have use that code from facebox github documentation.This event is working on my site at localhost.if working ,what is output text in alert box.    $(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() {alert($('#facebox div.content').html())});